# min() function in XQuery

Tags: xquery

I want to get the name of the zone, the number of products and the denomination of the product with the minimal stock order by the name of the zone.

I got almost everything except the denomination which prints nothing.

My code:

```
for $zone in distinct-values(/productos/produc/cod_zona)
let $numero := count(/productos/produc[cod_zona = $zone]/cod_prod)
let $nomzona:=/zonas/zona[cod_zona = $zone]/nombre
let $minimo :=min(/productos/produc[cod_zona = $zone]/stock_minimo)
let $deno :=/productos/produc[stock_minimo=$minimo]/denominacion
order by $nomzona ascending
return concat( 'Zona:', $nomzona,'   ',
               'Productes:', $numero,'   ',
               'Mínim stock:', $deno
```

The result:

```
Zona:Andalucía   Productes:2   Mínim stock: //here must be print like that "Placa base "
Zona:Extremadura-Galicia   Productes:3   Mínim stock:
Zona:Levante-Cataluña   Productes:4   Mínim stock:
Zona:Madrid-CENTRO   Productes:4   Mínim stock:
```

productos.xml:

```xml
<productos>
<TITULO>DATOS DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS</TITULO>
<produc>
    <cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Placa Base MSI G41M-P26</denominacion>
    <precio>50</precio>
    <stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>3</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
    <cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</denominacion>
    <precio>120</precio>
    <stock_actual>3</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
    <cod_prod>1012</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>Micro Intel Core i5 2500</denominacion>
    <precio>170</precio>
    <stock_actual>5</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>6</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
    <cod_prod>1013</cod_prod>
    <denominacion>HD Seagate Barracuda 250GB SATA</denominacion>
    <precio>80</precio>
    <stock_actual>10</stock_actual>
    <stock_minimo>5</stock_minimo>
    <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
</produc>
<produc>
```

the other xml:
zonas.xml:

```xml
<zonas>
<TITULO>DATOS DE LA TABLA ZONAS</TITULO>
<zona>
    <cod_zona>10</cod_zona>
    <nombre>Madrid-CENTRO</nombre>
    <director>Pedro Martín</director>
</zona>
<zona>
    <cod_zona>20</cod_zona>
    <nombre>Extremadura-Galicia</nombre>
    <director>Alicia Pérez</director>
</zona>
<zona>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks/Gracias/Merci

Answer (score 3):

You are not restricting `$deno` to the current zone, so for `produc`s with the same `stock_minimo`, this will return a sequence instead of an single item. So you should first add another predicate for zone:

```
let $deno := /productos/produc[cod_zona = $zone][stock_minimo=$minimo]/denominacion
```

However, if there were ever two `produc` in the same zone with the same `min(stock_minimo)`, you will have the same problem, so you can plan for this in your output by using `string-join` instead of `concat`:

```
concat( 'Zona:', $nomzona,'   ',
        'Productes:', $numero,'   ',
        'Mínim stock:', string-join($deno, ', ') ...
```

Comment: @user3325719 If you have any further questions, let me know; if not, please accept the answer :)